# Convert canvas to pdf : black background

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to export my html canvas to a pdf and download it, I did some searches and the following script works fine with me :

```
<script language = "JAVASCRIPT">
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// draw a blue cloud
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(170, 80);
context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
context.closePath();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
context.fill();
context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
context.stroke();

download.addEventListener("click", function() {
// only jpeg is supported by jsPDF
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
var pdf = new jsPDF();

pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
var download = document.getElementById('download');

pdf.save("download.pdf");
}, false);
</script>
```

But I am getting my canvas with a black background !

I have tried other codes and many solutions I found in the internet, I have tried to change the background color in the canvas tag, NOTHING had worked ..

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading as a `JPEG`, try downloading as a `PNG`:

```
download.addEventListener("click", function() {
// only jpeg is supported by jsPDF
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
var pdf = new jsPDF();

pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
var download = document.getElementById('download');

pdf.save("download.pdf");
}, false);
```

Comment: jsPDF doesn't support PNG.